# Add image to PDF - PHP

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

I have a PDF document with a text form field.

What i need is to replace this text form field for an image

Anybody knows how to get the position of a form element?

Or if it's possible to search items on a PDF, using FPDI or another library?

```
$pdf = new FPDI();

$pdf->setSourceFile("new.pdf"); 

$pdf->addPage(); 

$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);

$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, 0, 0, true);

$pdf->Image('image.png',150,250,25);

$pdf->Output();
```